# Ubuntu touch Keyboard

Tags: keyboard, ubuntu-touch

I got a BQ E4.5 running ubuntu touch, and I got a question about the ubuntu touch keyboard. Every time I use it I feel uncomfortable with it, typing errors, and have to correct every messages I write, which is hard since the cursor is really hard to place where you want.

Compared to the keyboard of an android or iOS it really annoying to use it.

Is there any information of it ? How can I give my feedback to the devs ?

Comment: I'd like to add that also the appearing and disappearing of the keyboard is a major annoyance. Instead of resizing the window to the visible area on the screen, the keyboard is placed over it, making stuff on the bottom of the page unreachable. Also when a text box is selected in the bottom half of the screen, the keyboard appears over it, and is not visible anymore. Additionally, when I want to interact with buttons on the screen again, I touch the button where it is visible. The keyboard disappears, the window moves, and I actually clicked another link.

Answer (score 0):

the keyboard is kind of awkward, especially with the special characters etc, and arrow keys would help there, I agree!

That said, the autocorrect is pretty nice, I hope you have that working at least, this is dependent on using the correct language. Especially when you use multiple languages that's not so obvious.

-Long press the globe left of the space bar, settings
(or go to system settings, language and text)

-Keyboard layouts, make sure in this menu that the languages you regularly use are selected.

-Go back to your message. If you long press the globe you see which language is selected, tap the one you want instead. Or tap the globe to change language (no feedback so you'll have to trust or check by long press or try that it is correct now)

I hope this helps. If not, it's probably best to file a bug report in launchpad, but that would require more detail on what's going wrong exactly

Comment: "That said, the autocorrect is pretty nice, I hope you have that working at least"